# How to invert the direction of arrows from radially outwards to radially inwards?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I've made a 3D quiver plot to show the electric field lines due to a line of positive charge. The result seems ok, as all the vector lines should be pointing radially outwards. But now I want to do same for the negative charge, so the vector lines should point radially inwards. But by changing

```
u = -x/(x**2 + y**2)
v = -y/(x**2 + y**2)
```

I'm getting the same result, the field pointing outwards. Can someone tell what's my mistake and how can I get the desired result, thanks.

Code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

x, y, z = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-4, 4, 5),
                      np.linspace(-4, 4, 5),
                      np.linspace(-1, 1, 3))

X = x*0
Y = y*0

u = x/(x**2 + y**2)
v = y/(x**2 + y**2)
w = z*0

ax.quiver(X, Y, z, -u, -v, w, length = 0.3)
    
plt.show()
```

[The resultant plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOp6N.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be mistaken, but my impression is this:

You plot a bunch of vectors all origining from (0|0) and pointing outwards to your (u|v) with (u|v) going around a complete circle.  Now you only change the signs of the (u|v), so effectively you will let your circle start in the opposite direction, but after completing the circle it will look the same.

Instead of swapping the signs of the (u|v) you should swap origin and destination of your vectors.

If I use

```
ax.quiver(X+u, Y+v, z, -u, -v, w, length = 0.3)
```

then I get arrows pointing inwards.